# Manipulating strings within structs C

Tags: string, struct

So I have a struct named task that initializes a few things.

```
typedef struct _task{
        char *task_name;
        int priority; // higher numbers have higher priority                                                                                                                  
        char date_entered[11];
        char date_completed[11]; // not used yet                                                                                                                              
} task;
```

I'm trying to write a function named task *makeTask that takes in (char *name, char *date, and char *priority)
I need to allocate memory for the new task, the name within the new task, and I think the date. So far, I've reached a segmentation fault using this:

```
task *makeTask(char *name, char *date, char *priority)
{
  int i;
  int j;
  int k;
  task *newtask = malloc(sizeof(task));
  for(i=0; name[i] != '\0'; i++){
    if(name[i] == '\n')
      name[i] = '\0';
    }
  newtask->task_name = malloc(sizeof(char *)*(strlen(name)+1));
  strcpy(newtask->task_name, name);
  newtask->priority = atoi(priority);
  for(j=0; date[j] != '\0'; j++){
    if(date[j] == '\n')
      date[j] == '\0';
  }


  return newtask;// FILE THIS IN                                                                                                                                              
}
```

I think I don't have a really solid understanding of strings and how to manipulate them. Why is my code here giving me a segmentation fault? Is it the loops or the way I've allocated memory for the struct? Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: You need to ask a specific question.

Comment: on which line is the segmentation fault occuring?

Comment: I'n thinking the segmentation fault occurs where I allocate memory or maybe the loops. I'm not sure.

Comment: @Vince figure it out.  If you don't have a debugger than use `printf()`s or something to figure out where it breaks at

Comment: @SamIam I'm slowly doing that. I've tried using gdb but I'm not too familiar with its functionality. Looking at a loop, for example, and trying to visualize its iterations every time it runs accounting for the memory addresses that get changed is still a challenge for me. So using gdb to look for a mistake in my coding is really complicated, for me at least. I'm still a noob at C programming as you can see -_-;

Comment: @Vince  Well then you can print text to the console using `printf` or whatever you use to print output.  If your program actually prints the text, than You'll know that the segmentation fault occurs **after** that print statement

Answer (score 0):

I haven't found anything yet that would guarantee a segmentation fault, but here are some issues.

your loops,

```
  for(i=0; name[i] != '\0'; i++){
    if(name[i] == '\n')
      name[i] = '\0';
    }
```

aside from being somewhat bizarre, You're presuming that `name` has been properly initialized.  If it hasn't been, then that loop will throw a segmentation fault.  the same goes for your `date` loop

the following line:
    newtask->task_name = malloc(sizeof(char *)*(strlen(name)+1));

`sizeof(char *)`, is a little odd, because you're initializing an array of characters, rather than an array of character pointers(an array of arrays).  I don't know if that really makes too much of a difference, but it is odd.

Comment: Hm. Well I assumed name was already included within the function through the parameters. Are you saying that, whenever parameters are passed through a function,  I still need to initialize say a *x to equal *name, for example, to bring those parameters into the mix?

Comment: @Vince my point was that someone can just call your function, and pass any old `char*` they want into there, and they're not forced to make sure that it contains a `\0`.

Comment: @Vince oh, and the `char*` is just an address in memory, so all of your changes you make to the memory referenced `name` in your function, will also change the memory referenced by `name` outside of your function because it's the same memory

Comment: Hm I think I'm understanding what you're trying to say. So I should probably be assigning my parameters to new variables within the function just to be safe?

Comment: @Vince or, you could check to see if it actually is a null-terminated string.  I personally would try [strchr](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstring/strchr/?kw=strchr) first, but there are probably other ways